# Highlight regular expression in grep window

Tags: emacs, elisp

I am using the grep.el package and was wondering if there is a way to have the regular expression I am grepping on highlighted at the top of the grep window.
Something like:

```
grep [reg expr]   ;Where [] highlighted
....results of grep....
```

Or at least at the title of window at the bottom something like:

```
*grep* [reg exp]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your correspondence at help-gnu-emacs@gnu.org, you don't need to highlight the regexp so muchas you need to be able to recognize it (see it).

For that, the answer is to repeat the command (e.g. `grep` or `grep-find`) and then use `M-p` to see your previous input, including the regexp used.

From that correpondence it seems that you are using `grep-find`.  In that case, the regexp is part of the full shell command that you entered, which is the only thing that Emacs saw (and remembers, and makes available via `M-p`).

If seeing the regexp as part of what `M-p` shows is not good enough for you then you will need to take the string difference between that previously entered command and the value of variable `grep-find-command`, which is the template into which the regexp was entered.  If you changed nothing else from the template to the full command you entered, then the difference between the two is your regexp.